# how to connect a html form to a database sql

Tags: php

im to connect a form to a database but the php is giving problems any advice to help my script

```
                 <?php
              $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
               $db = mysql_select_db("hot_data", $connection);


            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {


                   $userid=_$POST['userid'];
                    $first_name=$_POST['fname'];
               $last_name=$_POST['lname'];
               $livingadress=$_POST['ldress'];
                 $telephone=$_POST['phone'];

                  if($userid !=''||$telephone !=''){

//Insert Query of SQL
                    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO personal_data(userid,first_name,last_name,living_address,telephone)


                   VALUES('$userid','$first_name','$last_name','$livingaddress','$telephone')");

              echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
              }
            else{
                 echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!! </p>";
                        }
                     }
                           mysql_close($connection);
                  ?>
```

Comment: What, *exactly*, is the issue?

Comment: the problem is this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\morework.php on line 10 but then rewrote and its there ....

Comment: it has this  $userid=_$POST['userid'];
                    $first_name=$_POST['fname'];

Comment: Please clarify what the error is and what piece of code is throwing the error, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
try{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        throw new Exception("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    if (mysql_select_db("hot_data")){
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                     $userid=$_POST['userid'];
                        $first_name=$_POST['fname'];
                   $last_name=$_POST['lname'];
                   $livingadress=$_POST['ldress'];
                     $telephone=$_POST['phone'];

                      if($userid !=''||$telephone !=''){

    //Insert Query of SQL
                        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO personal_data(userid,first_name,last_name,living_address,telephone)
     VALUES('{$userid}','{$first_name}','{$last_name}','{$livingaddress}','{$telephone}')");
                    throw new Exception("Data Inserted successfully...!!");
                  }
                else{
                    throw new Exception("Insertion Failed...!!Some Fields are Blank....!!");
                            }
                         }
    }else {throw new Exception("Could not find database....!! ");}
}catch(exception $ex)
{   echo $ex;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should consider adding explanation

Answer (score -1):

You have an error on this line -

```
$userid=_$POST['userid'];
```

Should be this -

```
$userid=$_POST['userid']; // $_POST variable was improperly written
```

Comment: *Good golly Miss Molly!*

Comment: *[Evil-Eye Fleegle](http://www.comicvine.com/evil-eye-fleegle/4005-67696/) I ain't!*

Comment: "Eagle-Eye", si. Not "evil".

Comment: Seems like somebody didn't like your answer.

Comment: *Meh*, let them eat cake but leave us the icing.